# Stop people from pirating an application

Tags: windows, download, unreal-engine4

I am working with unreal engine as an indie developer. I made a game and I want to sell it to the public. However, i don't want someone to come along, download the game, and than they put it on the internet for free. Is there a way I can stop this from happening. I'm sorry if this is a noob question but it's important. 
Thanks

Comment: The first rule of DRM is: DRM doesn't work. So: If your game is worth it, someone will crack it.

Answer (score 1):

As Eugen say, if you release your game, there is nothing you can do to prevent someone from putting it on the Internet. All the effort you would put in it will be better invested into enhancing your game or promoting it.

Gamers do buy good games (and sometimes even bad ones) so trust them.

There are many business model which can help you make money with your game : freemium is one. Humble Bundle is an other one.